# Generar grafica de Highcharts a png o binario

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Buenas tardes, estoy intentando que al momento de generar una gráfica de highcharts la imagen pueda almacenarla en una variable y poder reutilizarla o genial seria convertirla a binario.

Dicha imagen la enviaré en un reporte. Actualmente al generar la gráfica logro que la imagen se descargue con chart.exportChart(); pero no logro capturarla en una variable para reutilizarla.

Leí un poco sobre PhantomJs pero no logre hacerlo funcionar.

Si alguien puede ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Comment: Cuando dices que la enviaras a un reporte, a que te refieres? Vas a enviarla al servidor?  Estoy viendo que la gráfica se genera como un SVG, que podrías guardar con formato SVG y usarlo de esa manera.

Comment: En un inicio yo quería generar el html desde sql server, el problema que ahí no puedo ejecutar js. Entonces mi idea era generar mi reporte en aspx y obtener la imagen desde js. Pero highcharts renderea la imagen en un div y no he podido copiarla o acceder a ella. A menos que lo q haya hecho este incorrecto.

Comment: la "imagen" es el elemento svg (y todo su contenido, claro). Puedes probarlo, generando tu gráfica, inspecciona la pagina, y copia ese código a un archivo de texto, y guárdalo con extensión SVG, luego ábrelo en algún visor de imágenes o el mismo navegador. Desde código, puedes acceder usando JQuery.  Según he leido, ASPX puede usar imágenes con formato SVG.